# Replace occurrences of string in a file

Tags: shell, sed, tr

I'm new to shell scripting and i'm having a situation here. I have a text file (let's call it `text`). I have `file1` which contains a string which needs to be replaced in file `text` with the string that is in `file2`. How could I make such a change? Also, all three files can contain special characters and `file1` and `file2` have only one line. Result should be saved in a separate file.

I've tried using `sed` and `tr` commands but I'm not sure how to make them use string from the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a better way to do it without using `cat`, it redirects the file output directly without spawning an external executable:

```
sed "s/$(<file1)/$(<file2)/g" < text > new_text
```

Answer (score 0):

`tr` isn't appropriate: it maps characters, not words.

To get the result of a command into a command line, use backticks. To get the contents of a file using a command, use `cat`.

There are several way to use `sed` to replace strings using regexes: my preferred way is "s/from/to/g".

Adding this all up gives you:

```
cat text | sed "s/`cat file1`/`cat file2`/g" > newtext
```